# When can we start submitting apps to the iOS App Store written using the Swift programming language?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I mean using iOS 7, as it is clear that iOS 8 will be released in the fall.
Put another way, can I publish apps written in Swift now using Xcode 6 beta?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store policy

Comment: We can't answer questions that should be directed to customer service. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/1864610

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the fall when IOS 8 is officially released. September 2014.

From the apple website:
"And when iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite are released this fall, you can submit apps that use Swift to the App Store and Mac App Store."

reference: https://developer.apple.com/swift/

Comment: Not sure why you're getting voted down, that would be my guess as well. Unless the down voter knows more information, which they should just comment instead.

Comment: Yesterday Sep 9th. it became official, for anybody stopping here.

Comment: I can't publish my swift app today, i've got email from apple: Invalid Swift Support - The bundle contains an invalid implementation of Swift.

Comment: @MihaelIsaev I have the same problem. Did you find out what the problem is?